# How to finish my batch file code?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I want to do following in batch file:

I want to open pdf, if it exist on usb. If this file don't exist, start pdf from another location, if this exist.

e.g.

```
:: Searchs USB Drive Letter
For %%I In (G,D,E,F,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z) Do If Exist "%%I:\Document1.pdf" (

xcopy /H /Y /C /R "%%I:\Document1.pdf" "%tmp%"
start %tmp%\Document1.pdf
)
```

I want to to open pdf document (from USB) if inserted. Once this .bat launched, and usb will inserted, launch pdf from temp folder. I want this without any error messages on batch.

Comment: What's wrong with the code your using? Or are you trying to detect when a USB drive is inserted?

Answer (score 1):

From what you have posted, I can only guess you are trying to run your batch file when a USB drive is inserted?

I'm pretty sure there is no native way to do this in batch, so I can only suggest you use an infinite loop on your batch and keep it running all the time, to detect any that get plugged in.

```
:LOOP
:: Searchs USB Drive Letter
For %%I In (G,D,E,F,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z) Do (
    If Exist "%%I:\Document1.pdf" (
    xcopy /H /Y /C /R "%%I:\Document1.pdf" "%tmp%"
    start %tmp%\Document1.pdf
    )
)
REM Use timeout /t 5 instead of ping if you have Vista or above
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5
goto :LOOP
```

and rather than loop all possible drive letters, I would suggest changing your `for` loop to this instead, so it only looks at drives that currently exist

```
for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%I in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption') do (
```

I have skipped the first 2 lines, as the first line is the column title and the second is 99% sure to be the `C:\` drive which you didn't include in your script.

Comment: Thanx for replying, but I want exacly this : For example, I have this batch file with pdf document After starting .bat, PDF copies to temp folder. If I would have .bat for example on desktop (NOT ON USB), it must launch pdf from temp folder (IF USB IS NOT INSERTED). if usb is inserted, launch pdf from any destination. –